# How to check a virtual machine free disk space and increase the size to a specified size using PowerShell script

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, powershell, script, vmware

I need help with a script to check if the free disk space is 30GB and if it is less than 30GB, increase it to just the difference to make the free space 30. I need this to work for 1500 VM's so it will can be automated to resize 30 VM's at a time. While requesting help elsewhere, a script was provided to accomplish what I am requesting, but no explanation was given as to how this works nor explains the mathematics. The VM hard drive is 70GB and has 24GB free space. So I only need 6GB extended in the hard drive. The script is below:

```
$space = 30 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 
$vm = Get-VMGuest $csvobject.vmname
if ($vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace -lt $space) {
   Get-HardDisk $vm.Vm | Select -first 1 | Set-HardDisk -CapacityGB (($vm.Disks[0].Capacity + $space - $vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))
```

While I'm not entirely new to PowerShell, I still have a lot to learn. The script below does not set the VM disk to a flat GB size, instead it sets it to 75.53621673583984. That's not what I need. Additionally, when I run the script against other drives I get the following (see screenshot) before it actually runs it.

[image: PowerShell Permission Image]

I choose "Yes to all" and then I get the following error.

```
Set-HardDisk : 2/17/2021 2:14:22 PM Set-HardDisk        The specified size '78219344' is less than actual size of the virtual disk '79205464'.  
At line:4 char:44
+ ...  -first 1 | Set-HardDisk -CapacityGB (($vm.Disks[0].Capacity + $space ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-HardDisk], InvalidArgument
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Client20_VirtualDeviceServiceImpl_TryValidateHardDiskNewSize_InvalidSize,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.VirtualDevice.SetHardDisk
```

I don't understand the error. It appears that the script is trying to set the drive space to 78219344GB while reading the current disk size as 79205464GB. I'm sure I'm misreading this error but any help explaining the script and how it works and the error would be appreciated. Ultimately, I just need a script with an "if" statement that will check the VM free drive space and if it is less than 30GB, extend the drive space by only the necessary amount to equal 30GB free drive space.

Comment: The actual error indicates you are trying to shrink the disk instead of increase it is the problem.  Are you trying to increase or decrease the size of the VHD?  I am about 90% sure you have to multiple the new value of the VHD by `1024 * 1024 * 1024` to get the correct size.  We can help you write the script but we won't provide you the script.

Comment: @Ramhound that is what I thought it was doing. I want to increase the disk space to just enough to equal 30GB. I just want the script to check if free disk space is less than 30GB, then increase the hard drive to the size that will provide the 30GB free space.

Comment: @Ramhound what I don't understand is why I get that message to set the disk size to 75GB and then errors out saying the prospective disk space is smaller than what I want it set to. The disk size on the machine I'm using now is 65GB so I know I'm not setting it smaller. I have not modified the script provided to me. It worked on one machine but not on others

Comment: purely as an aside ... PoSh has builtin constants for KB, MB, GB, etc. to me, 1GB is much easier to work with than `1024 * 1024 * 1024`. [*grin*]

Comment: @webby68 - What hypervisor are you using exactly?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey and Ramhound, I fully respect that you guys will not provide the script for me, however, I need to understand the script I have before I can effectively use/edit it to do what I want it to do. Please help my understand what this script is doing. I know it is checking the free space, but I don't understand how it is only coming up with 75GB, not giving me a flat GB size rather than all the trailing numbers, and I don't understand how the script can prompt me to get permission to set the capacity to 75GB but then say it is less than the actual size when it is originally 65GB before.

Comment: We need more debugging information.  What version of the [PowerCLI](https://code.vmware.com/web/tool/12.2.0/vmware-powercli) are you using?  What version of PowerShell? Within the if condition, create some local variables, and step through the code.  Since I can't debug the script myself, I don't have a compatible VM, one of those values I need to know is the value of `$vm.Disks[0].Capacity + $space - $vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace`.  It might be best if you modify the code to modify a single VM that has this problem, will easier for you to debug, and identify the problem.

Comment: "not giving me a flat GB size" - Because your code doesn't round `$vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace` to the nearest whole number.  I am specifically looking for the values of `$vm.Disks[0].Capacity` and `$vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace` this will tell me what type of units we are dealing with.

Comment: The Get-VMGuest is providing Sizing from a Volume perspective (File System overhead etc) and Set-HardDisk is working at Raw Disk. They are not the same. You'll also need to take into account the Disk may have multiple partitions and volumes on those partitions and they may not be using all available space. Resizing the disk will not resize the partitions so be sure to work that into your script. Disk ordering can differ from vSphere and the OS so for example Match on the SerialNumber (Windows) and vSphere vmHardDiskUuid not Disks[0].

Comment: VMware PowerCLI 12.0.0 build 15947286      Version 5.1.18362.1171

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance. I got it working now.

Comment: @webby68 - You should submit an answer, that would be the thing you should do since it took valuable time away from multiple different users to help you.

Comment: @Ramhound I posted the answer. I got tied up and wasn't able to get back to this until today. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: @webby68 - It would have helped if you had supplied the entire script.  Based on your answer it seems you had multiple problems.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the full script I am using. This script reads a .csv file for a list of vm's  to check a vm's free disk space and if it didn't equal 30GB, extend the drive space to make up the difference. I just needed assistance getting the "if" statement working. I ran the debugger and iterated through each break point and found that when  the program got to the "if" statement, it just jumped over it completely and the program ended without doing anything. With the assistance of a member of this site, it was determined that I needed to move the "if" state inside the loop. Once I did that and commented out some lines I no longer needed, the script works perfectly. Thank you all who provided input to help me get this resolved.

```
##Task Change Disk Size
##Variable clear
$csvobjects = @()
$cskobject = @()
$network = @()
$isalive = @()

#Get VM's to add disk space to
#$GetFreeSpace = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter DriveType=3 | Select-Object DeviceID, @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}, @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}

#Export to CSV

#$dateTime | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "D:\_Tools\PowerShell_CLI_HardDriveExpand-DiskFreeSpace-$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmssff").csv" -Append

## Creates encrypted password and stores it in the path specified. Only needs to be done once. To change the password, uncomment script string below, 
##delete "mysecurestring.txt", run the script, add new password and new encrypted file will be created.

#read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\Temp\mysecurestring.txt

## Wherever you see a -Credential argument on a PowerShell command then it means you can pass a PSCredential

$username = "domain.com\user.admin"
$password = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\mysecurestring.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
         -argumentlist $username, $password
##Import VM name(s)
$csvobjects = Import-CSV -path "C:\Temp\ExpandHDskList.csv"

Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false

connect-viserver -server anyserver.domain.com -Credential $cred 
#connect-viserver -server anotherserver.domain.com -Credential $cred 

#Write-Host "Hard Disk Space is equal to or less than 80GB."##Task Change Disk Size
##Variable clear
$network = @()
$isalive = @()

foreach ($csvobject in $csvobjects){

$gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
$space = 30 * $gb
$vm = Get-VMGuest $csvobject.vmname
if ($vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace -lt $space) {
   Get-HardDisk $vm.Vm | Select -first 1 | Set-HardDisk -CapacityGB ([math]::round(($vm.Disks[0].Capacity + $space - $vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace) / $gb))
}
##Variable clear
$network = @()
$isalive = @()
##Pre-change data gathering
$beforechange = (GET-VM -Name $csvobject.vmname | FT -auto CapacityGB|out-string)

# Variable specifying the drive you want to extend
$drive_letter = "C"

# Script to get the partition sizes and then resize the volume
$size = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $drive_letter)
Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax
}
```